# If a company is owned by both Muslims and non-Muslims, how can one pay zakat on the "company's savings"?

Tags: practical-islam, zakat, business, muslim-practices

Nowadays, it is common place to have partnerships in a company owned by both Muslims and non-Muslims. How is the Muslim partner liable for zakat if the company funding is not in his direct funding but owned by the company.

Is he or the company still liable to pay zakat? Is there an ijtehad on this subject among the contemporary ulema?

Answer (score 2):

Zakat is farz on individuals. You pay zakat only on your share of the zaktable assets and inventory. If you do not have enough money liquidate some shares.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide some references that Zakat is only for individuals.

Comment: You are the one apparently claiming that Zakat is a duty of artificial business entities, so you should provide a reference for that. Is Shadah, Salat, Sawm, Hajj done by individuals or entities? Zakat is only farz on Muslims.

Comment: @Ahmed there's an interesting issue would the Muslim state (bayet al-Maal) be asked to pay Zakat if the money which was collected and saved a year in it reached the nisab?